# C++ How to declare map variable

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm new to C++ and having trouble declaring a map variable in a header file. In various posts I've seen people include `#include <map>` and it fixed whatever their problem was so I included that in the file.

```
#include <map>

class Game
{

    typedef void (Game::*InputResponse)( void );

public:

    Game();

private:

    std::map <char[], InputResponse> inputResponseMap;
};
```

When I compile and build, it points to the `#include "Game.h"` of the .cpp file for the class.  `In file included from Game.cpp:8:` Removing the map type variable `inputResponseMap` fixes the problem so I assume that is where the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the line `typedef void (Game::*InputResponse)( void)` meant to do?

Comment: Better to use `using` if your compiler has C++11

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:c]?

Comment: @Isaac it declares `InputResponse` as a synonymous for a pointer to a member function of class `Game` taking nothing and returning nothing.

Comment: @MatteoItalia oh right... (I have trouble deciphering horrible unintelligible syntax like this) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::map <char[], InputResponse> inputResponseMap;
```

The `char[]` part of this is not a valid (complete) C++ type.

If your intent is for your map's key to be a text string, you should use `std::string`:

```
std::map <std::string, InputResponse> inputResponseMap;
```

And, of course `#include <string>`, for this.

Answer (score 2):

`char[]` is an incomplete type, and in general C-style arrays lack several properties that are required for map key types (in particular, C arrays cannot be assigned and cannot be compared directly through operator <).

Just use `std::string` as key type.